# Using global properties or build steps in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

I have a lot of projects in my TeamCity server, for building and testing multiple sites. We use Selenium RC to test the sites every night, and I would like to reuse one step or configuration instead of having copies in each project.

I have looked into using Templates, but they only seem to be accessible from the project it is defined in. The same goes for properties, as I tried to put paths and some shared values in system or environment properties and using copied build steps using those shared properties.

But it all fails, as none of these methods seem to be usable across projects. How do you solve this type of issue? It must be possible somehow, right?

Comment: So you've created a template, then associated (not copied!) your projects with that template, but when you modify the template property values those changes are not updated the associated projects?

Comment: I don't understand how I can associate the template with another project. Can you describe that? I've only seen usage of a template within the same project.

Comment: An old TeamCity blog [post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2009/10/30/yet-another-step-to-teamcity-50/) states that _cross-project associations between templates and configurations are now available_ and the [documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Creating+and+Editing+Build+Configurations?showChildren=true) states how to do it

Comment: @siyw: Wow, I must've missed that! That looks exactly what I was looking for - global templates with local parameters. Will try out soon.

Comment: Can I be a reputation whore and post that as an answer? ;)

Comment: This is perfect, thanks siyw! Will you post an answer with this, so that I could mark it as solution?

Comment: haha, yes you can! Didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per my comments for your question you can use a single template configuration build across multiple Projects.

See TeamCity [documention](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Creating+and+Editing+Build+Configurations?showChildren=true) for information on how to do this.

Comment: Saw that the documentation for 6.5 is altered: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD65/Build+Configuration+Template

Answer (score 5):

TeamCity has a new feature (as of 8.0) that supports global configs/parameters/env variables.   8.0 supports the new concept of project organization/nesting, and as part of that feature set *all* projects now inhert from the "Root" project.  And on that root project you can specify a number of things, including parameters, etc.  This does not appear to support build steps.

They documented the change in http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-11202.

[image]

--

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve a "global property" by creating a dummy build configuration which has your shared properties then for all your builds which need access to the global properties you create a build dependency. When your real build configuration is called it will first call the dependent build configuration (which does nothing meaningful) then it passes the properties from the dependent config (with a dep.bt prefix instead of just the system prefix).

Depending on the logic you need in a shared build step you may be able to actually perform real logic in the dependent build (it won't be able to inherit any properties or VCS details from the "real" build).

Comment: The dependent build suggestion is quite good. Feels a bit "hacky" for the moment, but it certainly works as you describe. Would be great if there was a possibility to send parameters to a dependency build. Will try it out and give feedback. Thanks!

Comment: This is a great way to share parameters, but I will give the solution mark to siyw for providing a more accurate answer to how to use templates.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a bit outdated, and the answers above aren't completely clear, thought I would post how I did this with TeamCity 8+.

Basically, a template can be used within the project and its children. If you move a template to the parent, it becomes available to all the siblings of the original project.

1. Go to the template.
2. Click the "Move" button (bottom-right pane).
3. Select a parent (or root).

Note: If the template is attached to a VCS root that is bound to the current project, you'll first have to move the VCS root to the same level to which you're trying to move the template.